# Silverlight, Ria running under https

Tags: silverlight, ria

Can someone post some configuration tips or settings on running silverlight that connects to an embedded ria service in the website under https.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/05/26/ria-services-using-https.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links, I had seen them before and tried some use some of the tips but my end result does not work yet. so let me go deeper. I added a client access config and silverlight works under https. but when silverlight tries to get data using https it gets no data and no error that I can see. So does anyone have any tips on getting errors from silverlight. this is in development so could I add a field or lable and post the error to that so I can try and debug why I am not getting any data back.